# Google Maps do not display properly in Jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using maplace plugin to display Google Map in jQuery tabs when you let off the map (second tab), the map can not load completely.

[DEMO ON FIDDLE](http://goo.gl/bt0ja4)

Comment: I think we need to see the important parts of your code.

Comment: most common approach is to use `refresh` method from google maps API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your map `div`:
 `<div class="map" id="gmap-dropdown"></div>`
outside of your `tabs` div, as well as some Jquery logic:

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9c4grxu/3/)

Comment: But that's not  what OP wanted, OP only wants it displayed in Tab 2.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to move the new Maplace out of the document load and into the tab click event.

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6xwwv1pg/

Reference code

```
    $('[data-tab]').on('click', function (e) {
            $(this)
              .addClass('active')
              .siblings('[data-tab]')
              .removeClass('active')
              .siblings('[data-content=' + $(this).data('tab') + ']')
              .addClass('active')
              .siblings('[data-content]')
              .removeClass('active');
            e.preventDefault();

new Maplace({
        locations: LocsA1,
        map_div: '#gmap-dropdown',
        controls_title: 'Choose a location:'
    }).Load();
          });
```